# gradlew decompliation error

Tags: minecraft, decompiling, gradlew, minecraft-forge

I wanted to de-compile forge src, but when I typed in the command, it gave me an error. What does it mean and how can I fix it?

> Last login: Sat Feb  6 20:59:20 on ttys000
>   Quangs-MacBook-Pro:~ quangnguyen200415$ bash   /Users/quangnguyen200415/code/nullum\ et\ vacuum/gradlew setupDecompWorkspace
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not locate the Gradle launcher JAR in Gradle distribution '/Users/quangnguyen200415/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.0-bin/5h57m9vra0mjv9qs45oqtsb5c0/gradle-2.0'.
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.findLauncherJar(BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:25)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
>       Quangs-MacBook-Pro:~ quangnguyen200415$

I am running latest version of **java 8**

EDIT: tried simplifying it, no effect

> Quangs-MacBook-Pro:nullum et vacuum quangnguyen200415$ ./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not locate the Gradle launcher JAR in Gradle distribution '/Users/quangnguyen200415/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.0-bin/5h57m9vra0mjv9qs45oqtsb5c0/gradle-2.0'.
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.findLauncherJar(BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:25)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
>       at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
>   Quangs-MacBook-Pro:nullum et vacuum quangnguyen200415$

Comment: It could not able find the gradle jar in configuration

Comment: @MohitSharma how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you've installed something that has either modified your JDK installation, or has messed with your 'JAVA_OPTS' env var. Are you running code from eclipse? it could be a change in Eclipse that is causing Gradle to be run with a different environment. Do you get the same error when running Gradle directly?

Answer (score 0):

```
bash /Users/quangnguyen200415/code/nullum\ et\ vacuum/gradlew setupDecompWorkspace
```

uhm... whats up with the preceding commands...

Just do ./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace

I'm pretty sure one of those commands you've added messes up the gradle path finding.

Execute gradlew without the fancy own commands, then add your own commands till it breaks. then you know what breaks.